# Group headers in a UL with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to add group headers to a `UL`.

I created something like the following structure (in reality this is build dynamically, from a database) :

```
<ul>
  <li class='group group-1'>
    <div>Group 1</div>
    ABC
  </li>
  <li class='group group-1'>
    <div>Group 1</div>
    DEF
  </li>
  <li class='group group-2'>
    <div>Group 2</div>
    GHI
  </li>
  <li class='group group-2'>
    <div>Group 2</div>
    JKL
  </li>
  <li class='group group-3'>
    <div>Group 3</div>
    MNO
  </li>
<ul>
```

I want to display *only the first* group header `DIV`'s of each group. The duplicate group headers should be hidden.

Please note, the group names (1,2,3, etc.) vary, since they are based on the ID's in a database.

I would like to do this in pure CSS, is that possible ?

Comment: If you would be looking for a jQuery solution: https://jsfiddle.net/gxfyezw7/

Answer (score 4):

You will have to go for each selector:

```
[class*="group-1"] + [class*="group-1"] div,
[class*="group-2"] + [class*="group-2"] div ,
[class*="group-3"] + [class*="group-3"] div 
/* and so on */{
  display:none;
}
```

```css
[class*="group-1"] + [class*="group-1"] div,
[class*="group-2"] + [class*="group-2"] div,
[class*="group-3"] + [class*="group-3"] div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='group group-1'>
    <div>Group 1</div>
    ABC
  </li>
  <li class='group group-1'>
    <div>Group 1</div>
    DEF
  </li>
  <li class='group group-2'>
    <div>Group 2</div>
    GHI
  </li>
  <li class='group group-2'>
    <div>Group 2</div>
    JKL
  </li>
  <li class='group group-3'>
    <div>Group 3</div>
    MNO
  </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

The CSS `~`Selector targets all following Siblings. Therefore `.group-1 ~ .group1 { display: none; }` will hide all `.group-1` Elements except the first one.

Dynamic Group names are usually no problem either, as you may target them using the `[attribute]` Selector. E.g. `[class*="group-"]` will target all Elements, which have a class that contains "group-".

It's NOT possible, however, to combine these two selectors and memorize/catch the wildcard-value using CSS only.

The CSS-only "solution" would thererfore be to generate all possible class-names (e.g. using SASS) and use the mentioned `~`Selector. Here is a working example:

http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/WxvGqe

This is in most cases a terrible idea, however, as you need to generate all possible IDs as classes.

Comment: Suuuuuper like for SASS idea

Comment: Sass is not going to help here. You'd still have to query the database for all the possible ids. Sass can't do that. All it can do is generate the boilerplate CSS for you. (You *could* write a script that queries the database and generates the Sass stylesheet for you, in which case you might as well forgo that extra level of abstraction and just generate the CSS directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Given your structure, you would need to be able to express, in terms of CSS, either

- "the first occurrence of an element with a specific, unknown class name", or
- "an element with a specific, unknown class name that follows another element with the same class name" in order to hide subsequent headers,

neither of which is possible, not even with Selectors 4's `:nth-child(An+B of S)` notation since you don't know the class names in advance.

If you can control your markup, I suggest splitting your groups into `UL` elements in their own right and having a single header per group. That is the most semantic approach.

If you have no control over your markup, the best you can do is using JavaScript to attach another class name to the first `LI` of each group and then hiding `.group:not(.first) > DIV` (where "first" is the additional class name).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via css `+` selector

```
.group-1 + .group-1,
.group-2 + .group-2,
.group-3 + .group-3
{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only change the element which you know/defined (statically) and you need it to works *dynamically*. so, you can use a little javascript code to accomplish that. basically you will hide all `li`'s using CSS, then show the first li which has a unique class

```js
window.onload = function () {
    
    'use strict';
    
    var liClasses = [];
    var liClass, i;
    
    var liLeng = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    
    for ( i = 0; i < liLeng; i++ ) {
        liClass = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].getAttribute('class');
        liClasses.push(liClass);
        
        document.getElementsByClassName(liClasses[i])[0].style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = liClasses;
    }
    
};
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: none
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: antiquewhite
}

p {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <ul>
    <li class="test elm1">1</li>
    <li class="test elm1">1</li>
    <li class="test elm2">2</li>
    <li class="test elm3">3</li>
    <li class="test elm4">4</li>
    <li class="test elm4">4</li>
    <li class="test elm5">5</li>
    <li class="test elm6">6</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm8">8</li>
    <li class="test elm5">5</li>
    <li class="test elm6">6</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm8">8</li>
    <li class="test elm5">5</li>
    <li class="test elm6">6</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm7">7</li>
    <li class="test elm8">8</li>
    <li class="test elm9">9</li>
    <li class="test elm10"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p></p>
```